# How to create this macro with conditions?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql, datastep

Sample input data: 
    `FirstName   LastName   Group   Age   LastVenue    Position`
    `Jack        Smith      ULDA    25     TheaterA       1`
    `Jesse       James      GODL    37     TheaterB       12`
    `Jane        Doe        ULDA    29     TheaterA       3`
    `Izzy        Gord       IIPA    41     TheaterC       8`
    `Ann         Roswell    GODL    30     TheaterB       16`
    `Chelsea     Jenk       ULDA    19     TheaterA       11`

I am trying to create: 
`%macro group_members(group=); 
    proc print data=sample;
    var Position Age Group FirstName LastName;
    where group=&group; 
%mend group_members;`

However I want to add conditions to it so if nothing is entered `%group_members()` then it will display all groups with the order of the variables shown above. If an invalid group is entered in this case: `%group_members(LOL)` then I would like a note to be sent to the log `%put 'An invalid group was entered'`. and therefor nothing should be printed. I am trying to create a program very similar on a much larger dataset. 

I appreciate any help in advanced! Thank you :)

So far I have tried:
`%macro group_members(group=); 
    proc sql; 
      select count(*) into :ct 
      from sample 
      where group="&group" 
 quit; 
    proc print data=sample; 
       %if &group ^= %then %do; 
          where group="&group."; %end; 
       %if &ct = 0 %then %put An Invalid group was entered; 
       %else %do; 
          where group="&group."; 
       %end; run; 
%mend group_members;`

I get errors from every test.. for example `%group_members()` returns an error of:
`ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined`

Answer (score 1):

1. Entering a blank resulting in all groups being shown could be achieved by surrounding the `where` statement with this macro code:

```
    %if &group ^= %then %do;
      where group="&group.";
    %end;
```

This only submits the `where` statement, in the event that the `&group` variable is populated. Note also that I've added double quotes so that the `where` statement doesn't generate syntax errors.

2. The macro would need to know which groups were or were not valid. This would require an extra processing step before the `proc print`:

```
    proc sql;
      select count(*) into :ct
      from sample
      where group="&group";
    quit;

    %if &ct = 0 %then %put An invalid group was entered;
    %else %do;
    ...
```

&ct will contain the number of records that match the `where` clause. If zero, then I'm assuming that means it's an invalid group.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to SAS Macro. Would I place the proc sql; inside the macro before the proc print?

Comment: Yes, the `&group` macro variable isn't available outside the macro, so it makes no sense for it to be outside.

Comment: I tried this but I can not get it to work... This is what I have: `%macro group_members(group=);
 proc sql;
  select count(*) into :ct
  from sample
         where group="&group"
     quit;
 proc print data=sample;
   %if &group ^= %then %do;
      where team="&group.";
   %end;
   %if &ct = 0 %then %put An Invalid group was entered;
   %else %do;
       where group="&group.";
   %end;
 run;
%mend group_members;

%group_members()`

Comment: One error I get when I try to use an actual group name such as `ULDA` is: `ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined`

Comment: @Jax remove `=` in first line;

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @mjsqu

Step1: Test if `&group` is a valid group. `count(*)` do this for you.

Step2: If count(*) return 0, then output user-defined messages.

Step3: Otherwise, continue `proc print`. If `&group =` then list all records.

```
%macro group_members(group);
    proc sql noprint; 
    select count(*) into :ct 
    from sample 
    where group="&group."; 
    %if &ct = 0 and &group ne %then %put An Invalid group was entered; 
    %else %do;
    proc print data=sample;
    var Position Age Group FirstName LastName;
    %if &group ne %then 
    %do;
    where group="&group."; 
    %end;
    %end;
%mend group_members;
%group_members();
%group_members(GODL);
%group_members(G);
```

Comment: I would suggest add `noprint` after `proc sql`. It will hide the value of `&ct` on top of `proc print` results.

Comment: When Group would be blank, your code would still print - An invalid group was entered,  also it would not output anything, which I don't think what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

/*Creating Sample dataset*/

```
data test;
infile datalines dlm="," missover;
input FirstName : $10.
      LastName : $10.
      Group : $8.
      Age : 8.
      LastVenue : $10.
      Position : 8.
      ;
      datalines;
Jack,Smith,ULDA,25,TheaterA,1
Jesse,James,GODL,37,TheaterB,12
Jane,Doe,ULDA,29,TheaterA,3
Izzy,Gord,IIPA,41,TheaterC,8
Ann,Roswell,GODL,30,TheaterB,16
Chelsea,Jenk,ULDA,19,TheaterA,11
;
run;
```

Have added comments in the code itself

```
%macro group_members(group=); 
%put &group.;

/*Checking if the group is valid or invalid*/
proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :num from test where group="&group.";
quit;
%put &num.;


data final;
set test;

/*checking if the group entered is NULL, if it is ,then it will output all the records*/
%if "&group."="" %then %do; %end;


/*If the group is Valid or not, if it is invalid then nothing will be in output and a msg in the LOG will be displayed, you can put ERROR statement if you want*/
%else %if &num. = 0 %then %do;
where group="&group.";
%put "An Invalid group was entered";

/*If above two are not the case then it will filter on that group*/
%end;
%else %do;
where group="&group.";
%end;
run;

%mend group_members;

%group_members(group=);
```